# Projecting 2D points on to a sphere

Tags: plotting

I have computed a list of data where the elements of my data list are of the following type:

```
RGBColor[0.8895841739153035, 0.6096297985979048, 0.2226442872878191], 
Point[{-0.000286314, 0.00616339}]
```

That is, each element consists of an `RGBColor[X,Y,Z]`, together with a `Point[{theta,phi}]`. I can plot this in 2 dimensional cartesian coordinates using `Graphics`:

```
 Graphics[SphData]
```

giving me this:

[image]

I want to plot this now in 3-dimensions, using the two coordinates of each point as the angle coordinates for polar coordinates (the points should lie on a sphere with radius 1). The picture would look something like this:

[image]

but with coloured points.

Comment: See [FromSphericalCoordinates](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromSphericalCoordinates.html) and then use Graphics3D.

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck?  Use `ReplaceAll` to apply the appropriate transformation to each `Point`.

Comment: If Graphics3D works the way I hope it does, then I guess I would like to implement a rule which takes each entry {Colour, Point(theta,phi)} of my list to a new entry {Colour, newPoint(x,y,z)}. At the moment, I don't know how to change Point{theta,phi} to Point{r,theta,phi}, to which I would then apply the transformation rule.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have figured it out. Following the comment by Vitaliy Kaurov, the easiest way seems to be to use `Graphics3D`.

I first extracted data points and colour points into seperate lists using combinations of `Flatten`, `Span` and `Part`. Then, I used a `ReplaceAll` rule to take each of my entries `(theta,phi)` to `(r,theta,phi)`:

```
ReplaceAll[Point[{a_,b_}]->Point[{1,a,b}]][datapoints]
```

Then I needed to apply a map taking my each point `(r,theta,phi)` to the corresponding point `(x,y,z)` in Cartesian coordinates. I did this with another `ReplaceAll`, together with `CoordinateTransformData` (I had some problems with fiddling this out, since you have to apply `CoordinateTransformData` to `{r,theta,phi}`, not `Point[{r,theta,phi}]`, but I figured it out eventually).

Finally, I converted my triples `{x,y,z}` into `Point[{x,y,z}]` with a `ReplaceAll`, then used `Riffle` to put the coordinates back together with the colour list I took out from the start. `Graphics3D` applied to the final list gives me the required picture:
[image]